# When proving limits, If I get $0<|f(x)-L|<10\epsilon$

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

If I get $0<|f(x)-L|<10\epsilon$ canI say that the difinition of the limit holds?, can I say that the definition of the limit holds? My reasoning for this is that the goal of the proof is to prove that the statement is true for any arbitrary positive real number. Since I am dealing with real numbers, it shouldn't matter if I have 10 times epsilon, as that is also just an arbitrary positive number. I can get all the same numbers that I can with regular epsilon if I go small enough.

Comment: You are right. $10\epsilon$ can be mage less than  any pre-assigned positive number by making $\epsilon$ small enough.

Comment: Yeas so you are saying that function is within 10e from L from both left and right. So as long as you are approaching it from both left and right, which is above in your equation and both within the boundaries of inequality, then you are good to go I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can argue formally like this. Given $\alpha>0$, you have shown there exists $\delta(\alpha)$ that makes $|f(x)-L|<10\alpha$ (for the relevant $x$).

Now, given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta(\epsilon/10)$.